# CAN network to LIN network gateway possible?

Tags: gateway, can-bus

I knew and worked on Gateway implementation in same kind of network i.e. within `CAN` network.
Recently someone has asked me, could you implement or design of `CAN` to `LIN` Gateway Network. I did not thought about this kind of implementation.

So could you help me to whether across the vehicle Communication protocol **GATEWAY** is possible or **not**? If yes, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do any kind of gateway, you just have to define the performance and the (transport) protocol.
 
Basically, information in a CAN frame does also fit into a Lin frame (both can hold up to 8 data bytes). So the easiest way is to define one Lin ID for each CAN ID that has to routed.
Of course you are limited to the Lin speed, what means you have either to reduce the update rate on CAN or route only every n-th message or whatever.
And you are limited to the max. number of Lin IDs, but if this became an issue, you'd better ask if Lin is the right choice for that system at all.

Answer (score 0):

@mic Do you have any sample capl script for this. If yes, could u please share

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.  In the future, when you have a followup question, please use the "comment" feature rather than posting it as an answer.  Thanks :)